# full calendar getting just the first event

Tags: php, calendar

I'm trying to fetch events from database to calendar but at this stage it just outputs the first event it gets from the database and the json when i echo it it returns just the first event

```
<?php
include("dbcon.php");

$events1 = array();

$sql345="select * from takimet";
$result = mysql_query($sql345)or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){            
    $id =  $row['agent_id'];
    $title = $row['ezitimi'];
    $start = $row['datestamp']; 

    $events1 = array(
        'id' =>  "$id",
        'title' => "$title",
        'start' => "$start"
    );

}
echo json_encode($events1);
?>
```

Comment: still it outputs only the first event in calendar here is where i fetch the json

Comment: events:[ <?php echo json_encode($events1);?>],
          editable: true,
          droppable: true,

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: i know man but im using php 5.5 anyway and im very familiar to mysql_ its a bit hard upgrading to mysqli or pdo

Comment: this problem  is not related to mysql_ though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over writing the same array occurance each time round you loop.

Instead

```
$events1 = array();

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){            

    $events1[] = array(                  //<--- changed
                      'id'    => $row['agent_id'],
                      'title' => $row['ezitimi'],
                      'start' => $row['datestamp']
                     );

}
```

Comment: ty but now it doesnt output the calendar at all

Comment: okay the events show now but im getting a weird output when i press weeks on calendar Mar 6 â€” 12, 2016

Comment: As the old saying goes, you only get out what you put in. That looks like a UTF8 issue.

Comment: with a restart that went away sometimes its not that coplicated